# Installing xampp on a separate partition to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, xampp

I've tried installing xampp (extracting from zip file, runing setup_xampp.bat) on a separate partition to windows. After the install MySQL starts fine, but apache won't. In the control panel it says apache has started on port 80, but the "running" message doesn't show. There's nothing in the error logs.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do differently to set it up on a separate partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with Skype trying to use port 80. Installing xampp on a separate partition is foolproof - just run setup_xampp.bat, and as long as teh port is free it'll run as normal